# Comparing the integrals of a function and its generalized inverse

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a nonincreasing and nonnegative sequence bounded above by $1/2$. Denote $a_{[k]}=a(k), \forall k\in\mathbb{R_+},$ with the brackets returning the integer part of a number and define $a^{-1}(u)=\inf\{k\in\mathbb{N}:a_k\leq u\}$. An author stated that
$$\int_0^1a^{-1}(u)du\leq\int_0^\infty a(x)dx. \quad (a)$$

Why isn't it only the equality? Can the R.H.S. of $(a)$ be strictly greater than the other side?

Thanks in advance.

*Note that $a^{-1}(u)=\sum_{k\geq 0} 1_{u<a_k}$.

Comment: Do you mean $k \in \Bbb N$ instead of $\Bbb R$? Or $a(k) \le u$? It is the $a(k)$ notation that has been defined for non-integer $k$ - but even for it, $a(k)$ is undefined for $k < 0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You are right, I will rewrite my question.

Comment: I "agree" with inequality $(a)$, intuitively. See that we are dealing with a step function. The R.H.S. is the L.H.S.'s analogue, corresponding to the integral of a generalized inverse function. I believe both should give the same area. I only didn't get the possibility of the R.H.S. being strictly greater (I know that the equality suffices to $(a)$ being correct).

Comment: I agree with you. If you take the graphs of $a$ and $a^{-1}$ and add vertical segments to make them continuous curves in $\Bbb R^2$, then they are reflections of each other through the line $y = x$, just like true inverse functions. And the integrals give the area of the same region. Probably the author approached their relationship in a somewhat different manner, got the inequality, and as that was sufficient for their purpose, they didn't pursue it any farther.